# Can't get json from Swagger + Jersey

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey, swagger

I have RESTful service based on Jersey 1.18.1 and I want to show my API via [Swagger](http://swagger.io/).

Firstly I have to get JSON. I read this instruction: [Swagger Core Jersey 1.X Project Setup 1.5](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5). Swagger allows to set up a configuration different methods and I decided to use custom Application subclass. I did everything step by step but I can't get JSON which I have to use for [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).

What I did:

 My custom Application

```
@ApplicationPath("api/v1")
public class DiscountsApp extends Application{

public DiscountsApp() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8002");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("swaggerapi");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("alexiuscrow.diploma.endpoints");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet();
    resources.add(ShopsResources.class);
    //...       
    resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return resources;
}
}
```

ShopsResources

```
@Path("/shops")
@Api(value="/shops", description="Shops")
public class ShopsResources {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "List shops", httpMethod = "GET", 
        notes = "List nearest or locality shops",
        response = Shops.class, responseContainer = "List")
    public String getShops(
            @ApiParam( value = "Radius", required = false)
            @QueryParam("radius") String radiusParam, 
            @ApiParam( value = "Latitude", required = true)
            @QueryParam("lat") String latParam,
            @ApiParam( value = "Longitude", required = true)
            @QueryParam("lng") String lngParam) throws SQLException{
                //The list of Shops objects is serialized to string 
                //using the custom GSON serializer and I know
                //that there is the better method of the solution of this task.
            }
    }
}
```

Some dependencies from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
</dependency>
```

After deploy application to Tomcat I tried to get http://localhost:8002/swaggerapi but I've got no result.
I didn't find the `swagger.json` in root of my application (`/tomcat8/webapps/app`).

What's wrong?
How can I get JSON with my API?

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:8002/swaggerapi/swagger.json?

Comment: yes. it's don't work

Comment: That doesn't help. What error do you get? 404 or something else? Are you able to access your own API at all?

Comment: i have error connecting to server.chrome: "this webpage is not available". Yes,  I can call API and application work fine. But app deployed on port  8080.

Comment: Then http://localhost:8080/swaggerapi/swagger.json?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /swaggerapi/swagger.json

Comment: That's when you do what? Is the context root of your application `swaggerapi`?

Comment: I have 404 code when I get localhost:8080/swaggerapi/swagger.json. The context root of application is `app` (`/tomcat8/webapps/app`).

Comment: then why are you trying to access `swaggerapi`? The location of `swagger.json` would be at the context root of your application. It's a JAX-RS resource just like any you register.

Comment: I use `swaggerapi` because I set it in `beanConfig.setBasePath();`. Ok, but after `http://localhost:8080/app/swagger.json`/`http://localhost:8002/app/swagger.json` call the json all the same is absent.

Comment: Even if `beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080"); beanConfig.setBasePath("app");` that after a call `http://localhost:8080/app/` isn't result.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what you set in the BeanConfig. The resource is mounted like any of your own resources and would be located at the same location.

Comment: The JSON file should appear at the context root after deploying application on Tomcat or after call some url?

Comment: It's generated at runtime. There's no 'physical' file.

Comment: Hi @Alexiuscrow could you please provide me the web.xml of yours.I have followed the all the steps given in Swagger Core Jersey 1.X Project Setup 1.5 website link but still I am unable to get the swagger file. I was bit confused for web.xml configuration.Please provide the web.xml if possible.That would be a great help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not correctly build the url.

Correct:

http://{host}:{port}/{context root of application}/{path from `@ApplicationPath`}/swagger.json

In my case: http://localhost:8080/app/api/v1/swagger.json

Thx to [Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103327/ron).

Answer (score -1):

adding a relative path worked for me (this is using .netcore 1.1)

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(s => {
    s.RoutePrefix = "help";
    s.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MySite");
    s.InjectStylesheet("../css/swagger.min.css");
});
```